# Returning a pointer from a class

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

For my programming class I have to write a linked list class. One of the functions we have to include is next(). This function would return the memory address of the next element in the list.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Set {
    private:
        int num;
        Set *nextval;
        bool empty;
    public:
        Set();
        <some return type> next();
};

<some return type> Set::next() {
    Set *current;
    current = this;
    return current->next;
}

int main() {
    Set a, *b, *c;
    for (int i=50;i>=0;i=i-2) a.insert(i); // I've ommited since it does not pertain to my question

    // Test the next_element() iterator
    b = a.next();
    c = b->next();
    cout << "Third element of b = " << c->value() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I need to set the pointer `*b` and `*c` to the memory address that holds the next element in the list. My question is what kind of return type would I use? I've tried putting Set and Set* in place of  but get compiler errors. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Set*` is correct.  You are suffering from a rather silly bug in this function:

```
Set* Set::next() {
    Set *current;
    current = this;
    return current->next;
}
```

The last line should be `return current->nextval`.  Otherwise you are trying to return a pointer to the `next` function... probably not what you want, ever.  :-)

Answer (score 6):

luqui is correct, although your **next** function is overly complex, there's no reason to copy the *this* pointer, that's just silly. Use this instead:

```
Set* Set::next() {
    return nextval;
}
```